# How to trigger a JavaScript function when clicking a button in C# toolbar

Tags: c#, javascript, internet-explorer

I have a button in my **IE** toolbar and I want to fire a JavaScript function when I click on it

Example:`$("#start").click();`

When I write `$("#start").click();` in the Chrome console it's working

Now I need to know how to fire this code from my toolbar button

I'm writing with C#.

---

I already have the JavaScript code.

I only need to know how to call this function from C#

---

Here is an image.

[image]

**EDIT 3:**
To be more clearer.
This is the function in C#

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Fire_Javascript_Into_Html_Page("Alert();");
        }
```

I'm guessing this is more clear.

---

I'm using an **add-on** to Visual Studio called "add-in-express"

This Add-on makes a toolbar for IE, after compile I have a .msi file that I can install the toolbar

This is what I have: Please look on the image below
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `onclientclick="<scriptname>"` property in the button.

Doing it from codebehind, I use something like this

```
/// <summary>
/// creates a javascript alert in the browser window.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="message">The message you wish the user to see in the alert.</param>
public void AMessage(string message)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "info only", "alert('" + message + "');", true);
}
```

to fire off a javascript alert from codebehind whenever I want to.

The same principle applies for any script.

Comment: No, if you are using html, you won't be able to use codebehind. But then, if you are using html, you won't need to use c#, you can simply use the javascript itself. If you are using aspx, you will have the aspx.cs file for code like that.

Comment: Maybe i'm not clear.
I'm building a toolbar that mean i'm building a plugin not a web page
That why i need to fire a javascript from the toolbar button
The button will be in the toolbar not in the web.
in the web i will have the javascript that know what to do with the fired function

Comment: I think you need to restructure your question. Fr0m what I can tell, you have an asp.net button on a toolbar which will be pressed by the user. When the button is pressed, you want to trigger a javascript function, correct? If you need to process data before triggering the javascript function, use the `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` function above in the C# code. If you just want to use the button to trigger the javascript, either do as suggested below, or use the OnClientClick parameter within the button itself.

Comment: I added a image to be clearer, I don't think that OnClientClick will do.. cos i need it to be for any html with out touching the html page

Comment: As mentioned below, why do you need to touch the C# at all? This looks like something which needs to be done purely with either Javascript or JQuery. You want it to be for any html but without touching the html...what?

Comment: Again, where you have `fire_javascript_into_html page`, you should be using ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript. as mentioned here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerstartupscript%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Sorry for the multi questions.. but you said that this will work only in ASPX.. and my toolbar will be on IE on every page. will this work on a simple <html><head></head><body><p>yada yada</p></body></html>??

Comment: If you are using C#, you should have an aspx.cs file associated with the file you are working on. What is the full name of the file you are working with?

Comment: Please look on my "Edit 4" on the main topic

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic structure of a jQuery click event. Just pass the selector for your button to the second parameter.

```
     $(document).on("click", 'button[id="myButton"]', function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var elementClicked = $this.attr("id");
        alert(elementClicked);
        callMyJavascriptFunction();
    });
```

Here is basic javascript.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function clickButton()
    {
         alert("Button 1 was clicked!");
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <input type="button" id="button1" onclick="clickButton()" value="Button 1" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Ofear the browser doesn't run C#, it runs javascript. You are probably using C# in the server, which is irrelevant to the browser.

Comment: If the only thing you need to do with this is fire a javascript function, why do you need it in C#? This will do just that, all you need to do is pass in the id for your control?

Comment: The answer above is what i seek, I know how to write javascript and how it's works... what i wanted is to fire a javascript function from my toolbar button and for that i needed to know how to do this in C#
Sorry if I wasn't clear